# Name a function as an environment command

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I wonder if there is a way to create a script as following :

```
#!/bin/ksh
export() {
echo "We're in the local function"
}
export
```

The main issue is that `export`is an environment command for setting value of a variable or an environment variable, so when  this script is run it will just prompt something like :

```
LOGIN=autosys
LOGNAME=autosys
MAIL=/usr/spool/mail/autosys
PWD=/home/autosys/wlp
SHELL=/usr/bin/ksh
TZ=Europe/Paris
HOME=/home/autosys
...
```

Obviously I could just name my function with a different name but as I am curious (and because this function should really be named export, logic purpose), I wonder if there is a way letting the script know I want to run the local export() function and not the environment command.

For example something like

```
    export(){...}
    call function(export)
```

Comment: Try to use the different name for the function in your ksh script instead of export. It mixes up with system function export, that is confusing.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer You're probably right, I was just curious to see if there was a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, export is a *reserved word* in shell. You **will** have to choose a different name.

Furthermore, you will have to source your shell script to apply any export to current shell instead of his son, forked.

If you really want to invoke something named “export”, use a shell file named “export”, for instance in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
/usr/local/bin/export bimbo lola juliet
```